# Preview Preview tab or right side window tool bar is not visible in Android Studio

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

Preview tab or right side window toolbar is not visible in Android Studio  3.4 for Windows 64-bit.
I have followed these instructions to try to fix these issues with no luck at all will post the link for you to see my issue.
https://hacksmile.com/solved-android-studio-preview-window-disappeared/

I don't seem to have an eye icon either. So I'm at a loss on what to do on this issue. I'm a new learner on Android Studio! I will post an image of the side toolbar for you to see what mine looks like and missing! [Android studio Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdIxL.png)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem a few days ago. I discovered it was just a problem with unsuccessful Gradle-project sync. So after a successful project sync, I closed the current project and created a new one; a basic app. That was it. Just ensure you do a complete project sync